# How to write my Name?

Tags: names

MY First Name is Sridharan,my last Name(Father's Name)is Sitharaman.How should i write my Full Name, as Sridharan Sitharaman or Sitharaman Sridharan?

Comment: What country are you doing your writing, and what circumstances are you doing your writing?

Comment: In general, in English, your "given" name is listed first, and your "family" name last, with any other names in-between.  People will call you either "FirstName" (when being friendly) or "Mr. LastName".(when being formal).  (Do note that many people with difficult first names pick a "nickname" that is easier to pronounce when people want to be friendly.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because names and naming conventions are cultural rather than linguistic. I asked a [question on meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4617/45432) about a similar topic that you might find enlightening.

Comment: Mr son-of Sitharaman. You should be telling us, not we telling you. Use of English in India has had quite some influence upon use of English in general (regardless that speakers in the UK or US disagree with that). Even if you no longer live in India, it is your heritage. Furthermore, I find it intriguing that Jews have ben/bat, Swedes have sen. Muslims have bin/binte/ibn, but people of indian heritage have not insisted on a Hindi, Tamil, Telugu, Malayalam, etc version ancestry conjunction. You should tell us and educate us.

Answer (score 4):

In English, the formula is often: (First/Given Name) (Middle/Maiden Names if any) (Last/Family Name)

Comment: "Often"? Weasel wording is weasel. Might as well write "whatever, duh" instead.

Answer (score 1):

The order you write your names in depends on what you're writing your names on.

Regardless of the order, your given name is called your first name.  Your family name is called your last name.  Strange but true.

Since you didn't provide a middle name I'm going to omit it.

If it's a letter, an e-mail, a name tag or a label you'd write it in the traditional order First Middle Last.  In your case: Sridharan Sitharaman.

If it's a form you're filling out they very often ask for it in a different order.  In such a case there will be a prompt letting you know the order they want.  Such as Last, First, Middle.  In your case: Sitharaman, Sridharan

Note the comma.  When names are presented in this order outside of a form the comma indicates that the names are not in the traditional order.  This is often done when listing names.

The non-traditional order exists because family names tend to be more unique than given names so switching the order makes manually searching through files or lists faster.

Comment: On a form, you might want to capitalize your last name, i.e. SITHARAMAN, Sridharan.  I do, because my last name has an unusual spelling, and I want it to stand out.  In your case, your names will look  similar to a busy clerk, so distinguishing between them will be helpful.